# IF AND FORMULA using conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, if

Im not sure if the IF and AND formula would work in this scenario but Im trying to use conditional formatting in 1 cell referencing off two other cells.

So in cell H13 has a certain date 1/14/2024 and in cell D22 and D23 which is a table have Yes and No's So I wanted to put a formula in conditional formatting to give me back if D22 has Yes and D23 has a No the fill color I chose will appear Vice versa.

Comment: are you writing an exam?

Comment: `So I wanted to put a formula in conditional formatting to give me back` ... give you what?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. 

Please edit your post to show what you've tried so far. If you show effort, others will be more likely to help.

Comment: Your question is unclear, it isn't possible to create a suiting answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use a formula for 'conditional formatting' you need to create one that returns "True" or "False" when you use *the same formula* **in a cell**.

To use such a formula for a table, first mark the table, then enter into 'conditional formatting' and use references to the first row in the table (i.e. the formula should work for the first row), or fixed references ($A$1) to values which are to be used for all rows/columns.